# FHIR: ImagingStudy annotation

Tags: hl7-fhir

We have an ImageViewer based on FHIR and we want to annotate certain images within a study.

We haven't found an adequate resource type for storing annotations line linear measurements, ellipse area, angle, text, etc.

On the top of that, the annotations shall point to a specific series/image pair, rather than the whole study.

What is the recommendation here? To create an extension for ImagingStudy (and have to update the whole resource for each annotation CRUD) or a separated suggested resource type?

Answer (score 1):

FHIR ImagingStudy is designed to work with DICOM imaging (and especially RESTful DICOMweb) and we tried not to replicate capabilities between the two. Among other reasons, this prevents some systems from only being able to see part of the imaging record.

Therefore, annotations and image flagging should be handled using DICOM presentation states (e.g., GSPS) and Key Image Notes. The ImagingStudy can reference those instances and request images be rendered appropriately.

We are always looking for feedback on missing use cases, so please let us know on chat.fhir.org if we’ve left a gap.